# Using the Total Probability Rule

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From one box with 6 white balls and 4 red balls, we pick out without replace 4 balls randomly and are transfered to another box which is initially empty. From this second box, after, are selected 2 balls randomly, what is the probability that the two selected balls are both white?

I have used the total probability rule, and arrived to the answer 11/84, but the book shows that the answer is 1/3, so I have problems with this.

I have used the rule by using a partition that consist in $a_{i}$ which are the possible number of the balls selected from the first box that are white, for i from 2 to 4.

From conditioning I have put that the answer should be:

$ {6}\choose{2} $    $  {2}\choose{2} $ / $ {10}\choose{4} $ $ {4}\choose{2} $ + $ {6}\choose{3} $ $  {3}\choose{2} $ / $  {10}\choose{4} $ $  {4}\choose{2} $ + $  {6}\choose{4} $ $  {4}\choose{2} $ / $  {10}\choose{4} $ $  {4}\choose{2} $

This is because i use that the probability need to be:

$  P(B) = P(a_{1})P(B|a_{1}) + P(a_{2})P(B|a_{2}) =P(a_{3})P(B|a_{3})   $

Comment: The second box turns out to be a distraction: you may as well have drawn directly from the first box.

Comment: It might help if you showed your calculation: What are the probabilities of the second box having $2,3,4$ white balls? What are the conditional probabilities of $2$ white balls from the different types of second boxes?

Comment: Ok, thank´s, the problem with the solution I gave is that isn´t counting well the number of forms that I can select the 4 first balls from the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A_2)P(2W|A_2)+P(A_3)P(2W|A_3)+P(A_4)P(2W|A_4)$

$=\displaystyle\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}\cdot\frac{1}{\binom{4}{2}}+\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}\cdot\frac{\binom{4}{2}-\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{4}{2}}+\frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}\cdot1=\frac{15+20\cdot4\cdot3+15}{\binom{10}{4}}=\frac{1}{3}$.

---

As Henry pointed out above, you can also think of this as drawing 2 balls randomly from the first box,

which gives $\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{15}{45}=\frac{1}{3}.$